# How can I receive JSON data from a API in same django project without using other module or library?

Tags: json, django, django-views, python-requests, jsonresponse

I have a API defined in my project which returns JSON data in response.

```
url(r'^api/report/(?P<report_id>\w+)/generate/', staff_member_required(api_views.GenerateReport.as_view()), name="generate_report"),
```

In another app of same project, I want to receive this data in views.py
How do I make a request to this url using some django functions. 
I think there might be some way to make this GET request without using requests or any other 3rd party module.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the problem with `requests`

Comment: I will have to add headers and all due to it's authenticated access and I wish to keep the code small and efficient with least number of dependencies.